# can not install mongodb for lumen

Tags: mongodb, laravel, composer-php, lumen

I am trying to install Mongodb for lumen from `jenssegers/mongodb` with composer. The version of php is 7.2 and have installed mongodb driver and added to `php.ini` correctly but I faced an error:-

```
C:\wamp64\www\lumen\blog>composer require jenssegers/mongodb
Using version ^3.4 for jenssegers/mongodb
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install jenssegers/mongodb v3.4.2
    - Conclusion: don't install jenssegers/mongodb v3.4.1
    - Conclusion: remove illuminate/container v5.5.40
    - Installation request for jenssegers/mongodb ^3.4 -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/container v5.5.40
    - jenssegers/mongodb v3.4.0 requires illuminate/container ^5.6 -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.3, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[5.6.x-dev, v5.5.40].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[5.7.x-dev, v5.5.40].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.0, v5.5.40].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.1, v5.5.40].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.10, v5.5.40].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.11, v5.5.40].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.12, v5.5.40].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.13, v5.5.40].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.14, v5.5.40].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.15, v5.5.40].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.16, v5.5.40].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.17, v5.5.40].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.19, v5.5.40].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.2, v5.5.40].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.20, v5.5.40].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.21, v5.5.40].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.22, v5.5.40].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.3, v5.5.40].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.4, v5.5.40].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.5, v5.5.40].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.6, v5.5.40].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.7, v5.5.40].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.8, v5.5.40].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.9, v5.5.40].
    - Installation request for illuminate/container (locked at v5.5.40) -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.5.40].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Fair enough. Doesn't seem to be another reasonable duplicate of this. Similar notes on this GitHub issue https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/879 Seems to suggest updating laravel. It's older but it seems reasonable since the library seems to be looking for updated dependencies which are likely present in updates.

Comment: Please share content of your `composer json`.